# Energy-momentum tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I need to show that:

\begin{align}
\mathcal
h_i^a \, T_{ab} \, h_i^b=(\nabla_i \phi)^2-\frac{h_{ii}}{2}[\dot{\phi}^2-(\nabla \phi)^2-m^2 \phi^2] 
\end{align}

where

- *i)* $T_{ab}=\nabla_a \phi \nabla_b \phi - \frac{1}{2}g_{ab}[\nabla_c \phi \nabla^c \phi-m^2 \phi^2]$ is the energy momentum tensor,
- *ii)* $h_{ab}=g_{ab} -u_a \, u_b$,
- *iii)* $(\nabla \phi)^2=-h^{ab} \, \nabla_a \phi \, \nabla_b \phi$,

with $\phi$ being a scalar field, $g_{ab}$ the space-time metric, $m$ a constant and $u^a$ the velocity 4-vector.

I have tried solving it but I can only get the second term right; I think there might be a wrong definition somewhere. I would appreciate if someone could at least point me to a book which has some steps of the demonstration.

**EDIT**: So far, this is what I have (NOTE: I think the problem is in part $C$, which is at the end of the post):

Substituting $T_{ab}$ (definition *i)* ):

1. \begin{align}
   \mathcal
   h_i^a \, T_{ab} \, h_i^b = \underbrace{h_i^a \, \nabla_a \phi \, \nabla_b \phi \, h_i^b}_\text{C}  - \frac{1}{2} \underbrace{g_{ab} \, h_i^a \, h_i^b}_\text{B} \, \underbrace{[\nabla_c \phi  \, \nabla^c \phi-m^2 \phi^2]}_\text{A}
   \end{align}

now $A$ can be written as (this part is confirmed):

\begin{align}
\mathcal
A &= -2(T_{ab} \, u^a \, u_b - \nabla_a \phi \, \nabla_b \phi \, u^a \, u_b) \\
& = -2(\frac{1}{2}(\dot{\phi}^2+(\nabla \phi)^2+m^2 \phi^2)-\nabla_a \phi \, \nabla_b \phi \, u^a \, u_b)
\end{align}

and since the last term on the right should be invariant, I choose $u^a = u^b = (1,0,0,0) \Rightarrow \nabla_a \phi \, \nabla_b \phi \, u^a \, u_b = \dot{\phi}^2$, so that $A$ becomes:

\begin{align}
\mathcal
A = (\dot{\phi}^2-(\nabla \phi)^2-m^2 \phi^2)
\end{align}

Replacing $A$ in 1., we get:

2. \begin{align}
   \mathcal 
   h_i^a \, T_{ab} \, h_i^b=\underbrace{h_i^a \, \nabla_a \phi \, \nabla_b \phi \, h_i^b}_\text{C} - \frac{1}{2} \underbrace{g_{ab} \, h_i^a \, h_i^b}_\text{B} (\dot{\phi}^2-(\nabla \phi)^2-m^2 \phi^2)
   \end{align}

Now $B$ is (from definition *ii)* ):

\begin{align}
\mathcal
g_{ab} \, h_i^a \, h_i^b &= h_{ib} \,h_i^b \\
& = h_{ib} \,(g_i^b-u^b \, u_i) \\
& = h_{ii} - \,h_{ib} \, u^b \, u_i \\
& = h_{ii} - (g_{ib}-u_b \, u_i) \, u^b \, u_i \\
& = h_{ii} - u_i \, u_i + u_i \, u_i \, u^b \, u_b \\
& = h_{ii}
\end{align}

since $u^b \, u_b = 1$. Substituting in 1., we have:

\begin{align}
\mathcal 
h_i^a \, T_{ab} \, h_i^b=\underbrace{h_i^a \, \nabla_a \phi \, \nabla_b \phi \, h_i^b}_\text{C} - \frac{h_{ii}}{2}(\dot{\phi}^2-(\nabla \phi)^2-m^2 \phi^2)
\end{align}

Finally, $C$ is:

\begin{align}
\mathcal
h_i^a \, \nabla_a \phi \, \nabla_b \phi \, h_i^b &= (h_i^a \, (\nabla_a \phi))^2 \\
& = ((g_i^a-u^a \, u_i) \, (\nabla_a \phi))^2 \\
& = (\nabla_i \phi)^2 + (u^a \, u_i \, \nabla_a \phi)^2 - 2 \, u_i \, \nabla_i \, \phi \,  u^a \, \nabla_a \phi
\end{align}

Now, do the last two terms sum to zero? If so, how?

Comment: Could you post your approach and what you have got so far.

Comment: I just added that information. The main issue is with part $C$, at the end of the post.